# Dropout not computed in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, dropout

I am trying to set an instance so that dropout is compute only during the training session, but somehow it seems that the model doesn't see the dropout layer, as when modifying the probabilities nothing happens. I suspect it's a logic issue in my code, but I can't spot where. Also, I'm relatively new to this world, so please cope with my inexperience. Any help will be much appreciated.

Here's the code. I first create a Boolean placeholder

```
Train = tf.placeholder(tf.bool,shape=())
```

which will be then passed into a dictionary value as true(training) or False(test). Then I implemented the forward propagation as follows.

```
def forward_prop_cost(X, parameters,string,drop_probs,Train):
    """
    Implements the forward propagation for the model: LINEAR -> RELU -> LINEAR -> RELU -> LINEAR -> SOFTMAX

    Arguments:
    X -- input dataset placeholder, of shape (input size, number of examples)
    parameters -- python dictionary containing your parameters "W1", "b1", ...
    string - ReLU or tanh
    drop_probs = drop probabilities for each layer. First and last == 0
    Train = boolean 

    Returns:
    ZL -- the output of the last LINEAR unit
    """
    L = len(drop_probs)-1
    activations = []
    activations.append(X)

    if string == 'ReLU':
        for i in range(1,L):
            Zi =  tf.matmul(parameters['W'+str(i)],activations[i-1]) + parameters['b'+str(i)] 
            if (Train == True and drop_probs[i] != 0):
                Ai = tf.nn.dropout(tf.nn.relu(Zi),drop_probs[i])
            else:
                Ai = tf.nn.relu(Zi)
            activations.append(Ai)
    elif string == 'tanh':   #needs update!
        for i in range(1,L):
            Zi =  tf.matmul(parameters['W'+str(i)],activations[i-1]) + parameters['b'+str(i)] 
            Ai = tf.nn.dropout(tf.nn.tanh(Zi),drop_probs[i])
            activations.append(Ai)

    ZL = tf.matmul(parameters['W'+str(L)],activations[L-1]) + parameters['b'+str(L)] 
    logits = tf.transpose(ZL)
    labels = tf.transpose(Y)

    return ZL
```

Then I call the model function, where just at the end I pass the values of the Train as true or false, depending on the data set I'm using.

```
def model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test,hidden = [12288,25,12,6], string = 'ReLU',drop_probs = [0.,0.4,0.2,0.],
          regular_param = 0.0, starter_learning_rate = 0.0001,
          num_epochs = 1500, minibatch_size = 32, print_cost = True, learning_decay = False):
    '''
    Returns:
    parameters -- parameters learnt by the model. They can then be used to predict.
    '''

    ops.reset_default_graph()   
    tf.set_random_seed(1)                             
    seed = 3                                          
    (n_x, m) = X_train.shape                          # (n_x: input size, m : number of examples in the train set)
    n_y = Y_train.shape[0]                            # n_y : output size
    costs = []                                        # To keep track of the cost

    graph = tf.Graph()

    X, Y ,Train = create_placeholders(n_x, n_y)
    parameters = initialize_parameters(hidden)


    #print([n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node])

    ZL = forward_prop_cost(X, parameters,'ReLU',drop_probs,Train)
    #cost = forward_prop_cost(X, parameters,'ReLU',drop_probs,regular_param )
    cost = compute_cost(ZL,Y,parameters,regular_param)
    #optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = starter_learning_rate).minimize(cost)
    if learning_decay == True:
        increasing = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
        learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate,increasing * minibatch_size,m, 0.95, staircase=True)
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost,global_step=increasing)
    else:
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = starter_learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    # Initialize all the variables
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    # Start the session to compute the tensorflow graph
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        # Run the initialization
        sess.run(init, { Train: True } )

        # Do the training loop
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):

            epoch_cost = 0.                       
            num_minibatches = int(m / minibatch_size) 
            seed = seed + 1
            minibatches = random_mini_batches(X_train, Y_train, minibatch_size, seed)

            for minibatch in minibatches:

                (minibatch_X, minibatch_Y) = minibatch

                _ , minibatch_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: minibatch_X, Y: minibatch_Y})

                epoch_cost += minibatch_cost / num_minibatches

            # Print the cost every 100 epoch
            if print_cost == True and epoch % 100 == 0:
                print ("Cost after epoch %i: %f" % (epoch, epoch_cost))
            if print_cost == True and epoch % 5 == 0:
                costs.append(epoch_cost)

        # plot the cost
        plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs))
        plt.ylabel('cost')
        plt.xlabel('iterations (per fives)')
        plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))
        plt.show()

        parameters = sess.run(parameters)
        print ("Parameters have been trained!")

        # Calculate accuracy on the test set
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(ZL), tf.argmax(Y))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

        print ("Train Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: X_train, Y: Y_train, Train: True}))
        print ("Test Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: X_test, Y: Y_test, Train: False}))

        return parameters
```